# problems with sending non-english text over mail

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding, email

I am trying to send non-english text over mail. The non-english text is on the "from" field of the mail (the text that appears beside the email address). In the recipient's mailbox, the non-english text is seen as a series of question marks. What could be wrong?

Previously, I was having problems with printing non-english text from a simple java program. The problem was with encoding used for the source file. I changed it to UTF-8 and could then print unicode text by embedding them into the program. Now all my source files are encoded using UTF-8. Could this be related to the above mentioned problem in any way?
By any chance, do I have to mention the encoding to be used for the message to be sent? If so, how do I do this?

Just to put in more context, this is observed in a web application that is hosted over google app engine and the program is written in java.

Comment: @Rubens sure Rubens..i got to know how to use it just a couple of hours ago

Answer (score 3):

You can *only* send ASCII text in headers. Non-ASCII headers must be [specially encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word).

Comment: is that so? are you sure? I remember having seen chinese/japanese characters in the "from" field of mails...

Comment: That would be because your email client transparently decoded the header.